# Formatting date iso 8601 date format with Time zone

Tags: formatting

I am using a format string yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 

and its working great for dates like: 2014-02-20T05:25:03

What should be the format string when adding timezone like: 2014-02-20T05:25:03-07:00

Or 2014-02-20T05:25:03.366+05:00

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Fomat string for what language?

Comment: language that will be used is c++ or java - i am not sure at this point.